# How to use Swift Decodable to map relationships from an array of UUID keys?

Tags: arrays, json, swift, relationship, decodable

I have a structure where:

`Factories` have many `Cards`;

But also, `players` can have many `Cards` (not implemented); they are the same cards.

For testing and internal integrity checks; I'd like to keep the array of cards seperate for now in its own JSON array.

So the structure I've come up with is like this:

```
// Example JSON
{
    "factories": [
        {
            "id": "7a24a713-c0aa-4498-....",
            "name": "Steel Factory",
            "cost": 4,
            "references": [
                { "id": "e936b897-c203-44a5-9cf0-27720f655b68" },
                { "id": "da35424a-6546-4c72-a51c-1f6abfd601a3" }
            ],
     ...
     "cards": [
          { "id": "e936b897-c203-44a5-9cf0-27720f655b68", name: "Card #1", cost: 4 }
          { "id": "da35424a-6546-4c72-a51c-1f6abfd601a3", name: "Card #2", cost: 4 }
     ] 
...
}
```

**Note**

> The Factory JSON structure has no `cards`; its considered to be an empty array when decoding

---

**Use case:**

> Fill the factories cards array (empty at init) with the contents of the references based off the matching UUID keys <

---

Swift structs are:

```
struct Factory: Codable, Identifiable, Equatable, Hashable {
    let id: UUID
    let name: String
    let cost: Int
    var cards: [Card]? 
    internal var references: [Reference]?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, name, cost, references
    }
}

struct Reference: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable, Equatable {
    var id: UUID

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
    }
}

struct Card: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable, Equatable {
    var id: UUID 
    var name: String
    var cost: Int

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, name, cost
    }
}
```

So, to try to do this; I've wrote out custom `initWithCoder` for each struct.

```
extension Reference {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try container.decode(UUID.self, forKey: .id)
    }
}


extension Factory {

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        id = try container.decode(UUID.self, forKey: .id)
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        cost = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .cost)
        cards = try container.decodeIfPresent([Card].self, forKey: .cards) ?? [Card]()
        references = try container.decode([Reference].self, forKey: .references)
    }
}

extension Card {
   init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
       let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

       id = try container.decode(UUID.self, forKey: .id)
       name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
       cost = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .cost)

   }
}
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
// Factory decoder 
references = try container.decode([Reference].self, forKey: .references)

// Find all cards that match the reference ID
// add the matched cards to this factories cards array
let matchedCards: [Card]? = references.map { $0  }
print ("matchedCards")
```

But I'm not sure what to map $0 against considering the Card struct isn't directly accessible via this struct.

I am aware I can just put the Cards to sit inside the factories struct as a child array.

But I'm thinking ahead, there might come a time in the future where I need a bridging struct with key references like a `one to many through` JSON structure.

I appreciate any feedback offered.

Comment: For this type of data I would suggest looking at using YAML instead of JSON. There're `Coder` implementations for YAML->Swift.

Comment: I didn't know that; I will look at YAML for swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let referenceIds:[String] = references.map { $0.id }

let decodedCards = container.decode([Card].self, forKey: .cards)

let matchedCards[Card] = decodedCards.filter(where: { referenceIds.contains($0.id)})

self.cards = matchedCards // factory.cards
```

Comment: This struct doesn't have access to self.cards at all.   It doesn't know about the cards.  The "cards" are decoded in their own struct.   I think what you mean is I need to have a custom initWithCoder where I pass in the cards?   The structs are in different files

Comment: I'll give it a go.  Thank you

Comment: I wish to thank you for your assistance.  I can see how this might work; however when loading and initing the factory the card array is empty.    `cards: []`    and the idea I wanted to play with was, can I fill this empty array with IDs in the `references` collection of matching UUIDs.    I think I might just keep it simple and dump the cards to sit under the parents.

Comment: I put a breakpoint in;   `po [Card].self` returns  `Swift.Array<EngineYard.Card>`   Its an empty array

Comment: In that case i am afraid you cannot unless you have access to the cards. You can try to use custom init which taking cards and call super. Initfromdecoder here you would have a reference to the cards

Comment: I agree.  I wonder how other apps do this where they have a one-to-many relationship or a many-to-many relationship.  Surely they don't make multiple calls?   Anyway, I'm going to have to leave it and just move all the children under the parent and leave it as that.   I think there is a bit of a clue in `nestedContainer`    accepted answer for now

Comment: Nested container is used for the nested json. You said that json doesnt have cards. Why multiple calls?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion; the JSON structure holds information about 2 things factories and cards.   The factory structure by default has no cards; but it holds references (keys) to the cards array.   I'll try to see how others do it, but for now, I'm happy to accept the answer, I think its being too complex for no reason.

Comment: if json has the cards then you can simply parse them from the container as i wrote in the answer.